# how to fix iframe load never terminating the browser visual spinner and 'Transfer ...' status

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have pages loading json into hidden iframes from javascript.

The Firefox browser seems to never acknowledge fully receiving the iframe content, and reports 'Transferring data from ...' on the status line, and shows the twirly 'busy' icon on the tab, indefinitely.

I am using jQuery to bind the 'load' handlers, and would prefer a solution that does not involve over-riding jQuery functionality.

btw, the load handler does fire, the json received is complete, and the iframe itself gets .remove()d in the cleanup code.  The browser still waits for something to signal completeness.

Comment: I'm actually curious about this myself. I have a site where I've implemented facebook 'like' buttons under each 'item' (using the iframe technique) and some browsers report indefinite loading. Good question!

Comment: Are you sure the JSON is valid. If it's invalid both the success and error function won't be called. A timer is in this case the best solution.

Comment: how would a timer be useful?  What code would the timeout call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ben Nadel posted a [blogpost](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1336-FireFox-Never-Stops-Loading-With-iFrame-Submission.htm) on just this topic.

It seems that Firefox acknowledges that an iframe document was completely received only after the onload handler returns. If the iframe is deleted from the DOM within the handler, Firefox never detects completion. The solution Mr Nadel suggested, and which I used, is to use the javascript timer to call a deletion function to run after a brief delay. This allows the handler to return while the iframe persists, but does not let the iframe linger around.